# Can't gain write access to secondary hard drive root-level folder

Tags: hard-drive, folders

I have a second hard drive installed on my Mac. On its several root-level folders there's only one I can't get write access to.

I've tried right-clicking it, select "Get Info", unlock it, click the plus sign, select my name, change my name, & everyone to "Read only to "Read & Write", click the gear icon, "Make Me the owner" & "Apply to enclosed items."

Even after repeating those steps I still can't rename or delete this folder. How can I gain write access to it?

Comment: To rename or delete a folder, you need the proper permissions on the *parent* folder.

Comment: @ughovavghfw There isn't a parent folder; this is a root-level folder I'm trying to rename/delete.

Comment: @am1rr3za That posts regards an NTFS hard drive. This is a Mac OS (Journaled) hard drive.

Comment: If it's a folder at the root of a volume, then the parent folder is the volume itself.  What're the permissions on that?  Also, the Finder doesn't always show all permissions -- try from Terminal with `ls -leOd ` and then drag the folder and the volume onto the Terminal window before pressing return.

Comment: @Gordon - thank you. I didn't realize the actual drive itself had permissions. Changing those and applying to enclosed items did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need permissions to exist on this volume?  If not use the "Ignore permissions on this volume" checkbox, and that will take care of all of the problems.

Also - I would run disk utility's verify to see if there are any problems with it.